# Алгоритм простых чисел в JS

Tags: javascript

**Понимаю как нелепо может выглядеть этот вопрос,и как криво я описал проблему,но я новичок в этом деле,так что сорре**

Учу сейчас JS на learn.javascript.ru,дошел до раздела функции.Там можно встретить такой вот алгоритм:

```js
function showPrimes(n) {
  nextPrime: for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {

    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
    }

    alert( i ); // простое
  }
}

showPrimes(10);
```

Не понимаю как оно работает,пробовал уже и на бумажке смотреть.Функция собственно выводит простые числа от 2 до n.Вот как по мне должна работать функция:

Вызываем функцию `showPrimes()` со значением `10` >>

Изначально `i` во внешнем цикле,и `j` во внутреннем равны 2,так что внутренний цикл не срабатывает и выводится 2 `(alert(i))`>>

Переходим на следующую итерацию внешнего цикла,`i` становиться 3 >>

Срабатывает внутренний `for`,идет проверка на остаток деления >>

Т.к остаток от деления 3 на 2 не является 0,`continue` не срабатывает>>

теперь уже внутренний цикл начинает новую итерацию,`j` становится 3,`i` у нас также остается 3 значит цикл не срабатывает и alert выводит 3 >>

`i = 4 j = 3`,внутренний цикл срабатывает,остаток не равен 0 значит переходим на след.итерацию `j` становиться 4,а значит внутренний цикл не запускается и выводится 4,но 4 выводится не должно(да и не выводится,программа работает корректно,просто я не правильно все понимаю скорее всего) Так где же я не прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. во внутреннем цикле условие `j < i`, то `j` никогда не будет равно `i` и комбинация `4%4` попросту не вычисляется, а начинается следующая итерация внешнего цикла с i = 5.

При каждом новом j внутренний цикл стартует заново (с 2), поэтому проверка 4 (и вообще всех четных чисел) 
заканчивается уже на 2, так как 4%2 равняется 0.

Comment: Как же?Допустим у  нас уже i = 4 и j = 3,когда во внутреннем цикле i поделится на j и continue не сработает,то тело цикла закончится и выполнится шаг( j++ ) и j станет 4.Или у меня не правильно представление о работе for?

Comment: j станет 4 и итерация цикла не будет выполняться, потому что не выполняется условие j<i.

Comment: Ну да,внутренний цикл не выполнится,соответственно продолжит выполнятся внешний,там идет alert() который выведет 4

Comment: Хм, действительно. А если делать до 11, то 11 выведет?

Comment: Нет, не выведет,ведь условие(как ты написал про 11) i<11,а не i <= 11,но я не понимаю к чему этот саркастический вопрос,поясни мне барашику(если не впадлу) почему когда j и i становятся 4 не продолжает выполнятся внешний цикл,и alert не выводит 4?

Comment: Тьфу, запутал меня!  Проверка 4 заканчивается же уже на двойке. Остаток равен нулю и цикл прерывается, т.е. там даже до трёх не доходит.

Answer (score 1):

Пропустив этот момент я продолжил изучать учебник дальше,дошел до изучения отладчика и воспользовался им,дело в том что `j` во внутреннем цикле постоянно сбрасывает свое значение к двум при каждой итерации внешнего цикла.Короче совет таким же бубунам как и я,используйте отладчик:)